# WCF Service - Proxy Class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a web reference and created proxy class using svcutil.exe but the provided class is of `System.Xml.XmlElement` where my methods are of `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` so it generates an error.
My question is how can I generate `proxy` class with `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`.

```
public  XElement GetXMLFromDeveopmentForAllLanguages(string ItemID)
    {
        XElement ReturnElement = default(XElement);
        ReturnElement = sitecoreDev.GetXML(ItemID, false, Constants.MasterDatabase, DevCredentials);
        return ReturnElement.Descendants().Elements("item").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value == ItemID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Error is:

```
cannot implicitly convert type 'system.xml.xmlelement' to 'system.xml.linq.xelement'
```

Comment: Can you post some code/samples, please?

Comment: This is when webreference added:                              public XElement GetXML(string id, bool deep, string databaseName, Credentials credentials);                                              My dynamic class provided                                  public System.Xml.XmlElement GetXML(string id, bool deep, string databaseName, sitecore.net.visual.Credentials credentials)         {                                                                 }

Comment: Please provide complete example code and the exact error message you get (do so by editing / adding to your question, not comments). By default [XElement is supported in DataContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so it is not entirely clear what is wrong here.

Comment: What is the method signature in web service/WCF service? You cannot alter that unless you have control over service code itself.

Comment: It is System.Xml.XmlElement

Comment: That's a bad design.. You should return a business object

Comment: Might be, but my question is why it is generating XmlElement instead of XElement?

Answer (score 0):

When adding a Service Reference, you get two options

- Reuse types in **all** referenced assemblies and
- Reused types in **specified** reference assemblies

Select specified reference assemblies option and uncheck **System.Xml.Linq** assembly

**XElement** can be serialized only into **XmlElement** and **DataContractSerializer** - check  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675182.aspx

Comment: I would like to have my proxy class in System.Xml.Linq format

Comment: XElement can be serialized only into XmlElement and DataContractSerializer

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get you as I'm new to this topic

Comment: All objects used in WCF service methods need to be serialized. Hence, they should be serializable. XElement implements IXmlSerializable - which will be serialized using XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer. I would recommend using your own object instead of just passing a heavy object like XElement

Comment: Also client doesn't know which .NET type has been used and service reference informs it only that any XML can be returned. It takes XML and provides it as XElement